# Basic Python Scraper with TypeError: object of type 'Response' has no len()

Tags: python, beautifulsoup

I'm new to coding a webscraper with Python. I've done a few tutorials and now I am trying my first one. A really simple test here that yields the error I noted in the Subject line.

```
import requests
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
url = "https://www.autotrader.ca/cars/mercedes-benz/ab/calgary/?rcp=15&rcs=0&srt=3&prx=100&prv=Alberta&loc=T3P%200H2&hprc=True&wcp=True&sts=Used&adtype=Private&showcpo=1&inMarket=advancedSearch"
user_agent = 'Mozilla/5.0 (Macintosh; Intel Mac OS X 10_9_3) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/71.0.3578.98  Safari/537.36'
html = requests.get(url,headers={'User-Agent': user_agent})
soup = BeautifulSoup(html, "lxml")
print(soup)
```

Please help me out with trying out this code. Any help is greatly appreciated!

Comment: Your code is badly formatted. You need to use `html.text` instead of `html`.

Comment: Thanks Tomasz. This is my first post here. I used the "Code" input in the text editor.  Thanks for the quick answer!

Answer (score 1):

Use `html.text` instead of `html`. It's a good practice to send the headers binded with user-agent inside the get() method.

```
import requests
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup

url = "https://www.autotrader.ca/cars/mercedes-benz/ab/calgary/?rcp=15&rcs=0&srt=3&prx=100&prv=Alberta&loc=T3P%200H2&hprc=True&wcp=True&sts=Used&adtype=Private&showcpo=1&inMarket=advancedSearch"

headers = {'User-Agent': 'Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; Win64; x64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/60.0.3112.113 Safari/537.36'}
response = requests.get(url,headers=headers)
soup = BeautifulSoup(response.text,"lxml")
return soup
```

Answer (score 0):

Make changes in this line:

```
soup = BeautifulSoup(html, "lxml")
```

to

```
soup = BeautifulSoup(html.content, "lxml")
```

or

```
soup = BeautifulSoup(html.text, "lxml")
```

This returns the HTML structure of the webpage.